# Do visits to Cyprus, Croatia, Bulgaria and Romania count towards Schengen limitations?

Tags: schengen, romania, croatia, bulgaria, cyprus

If I am entering any of the countries mentioned above with a Schengen visa - does the time spent there count towards the overall restriction of 90 days within 180 days? Does the time spent within the Schengen area reduce the time I would be allowed to stay in these countries?

Is it possible to stay in Europe for an entire year by combining stays in these countries and the Schengen area under a single Schengen multivisa?

Additionally, does the same apply to these countires recognizing each others visas? Would the time spent in Croatia on a Cyprus visa count towards the restrictions of said Cyprus visa? If so, will it not count if I get separate visas for Cyprus and Croatia?

---

A bit of background here. I thought that all the limitations do count unless you get separate visas, but a friend of mine argues that these countries count stays entirely separately from each other and thus it would be possible to stay in Europe for an entire year on just a Schengen multivisa by cycling through these countries. I do want to know whetever this is the case. The reason I think all the limitations apply is because all of these countires are part of the EU and should comply with the same Schengen acquis

Comment: Time spent in the other countries does not count, but I don't have a reference at the moment.  If I find one later, I'll post a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

@phoog is correct. This is explained in [Schengen Borders Code (amended)](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32016R0399)  in article 6:

> 1. For intended stays on the territory of the Member States of a duration of no more than 90 days in any 180-day period, which entails
>      considering the 180-day period preceding each day of stay, the entry
>      conditions for third-country nationals shall be the following...

"Member States" here means those who signed the Schengen agreement.

[Decision No 565/2014/EU](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=celex:32014D0565) asks (Article 5) RO/BG/CR to accept Schengen visas (and residency permits) in lieu of national visas for entry into RO/BG/CR. If they are accepted, they must be accepted under standard 90/180 rule (article 2). It does not make Romania the "Member state", and 90/180 rule would in this case apply independently.

Looking at this particular text:

> The entry conditions for third-country nationals whose intended stays
>   on the territory of the Member States have a duration of no more than
>   90 days in any 180-day period ... in so far as this Decision sets up a
>   regime of unilateral recognition by Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus and
>   Romania of certain documents issued by Member States fully
>   implementing the Schengen acquis ... for transit through **or intended
>   stays on their territories** not exceeding 90 days in any 180-day
>   period.

it seems pretty clear that it makes difference between 90/180 days on the territory "of Member States", and "on their territories"

PS. The above is of course non-legal opinion - if you need an official legal opinion, you should consult a lawyer.

Comment: Here's an EU decision concerning the countries I mentioned: https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=celex:32014D0565
It mentions "Schengen acquis" extensively, but I can't find any clear language explaining this particular detail.
Could you base your answer on this particular EU decision, breaking down what it says for those who are not good with legalese?

Comment: @user4551 the decision you link to has nothing to say about its impact (or lack of impact) on the accounting of presence in the "territory of the member states" for the Schengen Borders code.