# Schengen visa used in non-EU country can it be reused in EU?

Tags: visas, schengen, eu

I have a Swedish visa issued for 1 year, multiple entries, duration of stay 90 days.  I used this visa to stay 82 days in Colombia.  Can I use it again to stay in an EU country?  It is valid until March 2019.

Comment: [Colombia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colombia) is a [Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area) country?

Comment: @BasilBourque Colombia is of course *not* a Schengen country, but it offers a [visa exemption for people with Schengen visas (among other documents)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Colombia#Substitute_visa).

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can use the visa to visit the Schengen area or the other EU countries that honor Schengen visas (not the UK or Ireland).  The fact that other countries unilaterally offer visa exemptions for those who hold Schengen visas does not affect the use of those visas in the Schengen area.

This assumes that there's no other reason preventing you from using the visa, of course.  Such reasons could arise regardless of whether you use the visa for a visa exemption in Colombia.

Comment: There are other EU countries as well which are not Schengen.

Comment: @lalala yes, but those countries admit Schengen visa holders on the basis of a Schengen visa.  I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: good point! Didnt think of that.

Comment: That’s, of course, if the visa holder’s situation has not changed too much, and the details for the stay in the Schengen Area still (at least somewhat) match those that were presented when the visa was requested.

Comment: @jcaron Fair enough, I've edited to clarify.

Comment: What happens if you use a Schengen visa in a non-Schengen EU country that recognizes it, such as Croatia. Would the time there still count against the 90-in-180 day limit?

Comment: @dbkk No. See [Do visits to Cyprus, Croatia, Bulgaria and Romania count towards Schengen limitations?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/111893/19400)